# React @material-ui/core - v4.11.0 - "the createMuiTheme function was renamed to createTheme" console error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My react project only logging this error(console error) when the service on production level. I don't see the following error on my local, but only on production mode.

```
Material-UI: the createMuiTheme function was renamed to createTheme. You should use `import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'`
```

I found a few articles saying this only happens when anything above `v5 of @material-ui/core` has been used. However, I'm using `v4.11.0 of @material-ui/core` which only supports `createMuiTheme`. Since the version is below `v5`, I reckon the error should not be shown at any point during runtime.

For those who have any clue regarding this issue, please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same goes to me.
Probably updated deprecated function name createMuiTheme to createTheme used in ThemeProvider.

https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/pull/1885

Comment: You are the legend. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
instead of import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';